# Error deploying smart contract using Hardhat -- Error HH9: Error while loading Hardhat's configuration

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

Trying to deploy a smart contract using Hardhat but getting configuration error.

Here is the complete error details

```
Error HH9: Error while loading Hardhat's configuration.
You probably tried to import the "hardhat" module from your config or a file imported from it.
This is not possible, as Hardhat can't be initialized while its config is being defined.
```

All the plug-ins seem to be have been installed correctly.

> deploy.js

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const TestContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TestContract");
  const superInstance = await TestContract.deploy("TestContractHAT", "SMC");
  await superInstance.deployed();
  console.log("contract was deployed to:", superInstance.address());
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This project demonstrates a basic Hardhat use case. It comes with a sample contract, a test for that contract, a sample script that deploys that contract, and an example of a task implementation, which simply lists the available accounts.",
  "main": "hardhat.config.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.3"
  }
}
```

> Hardhat.config

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require('@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades');


require("dotenv").config();
// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();  
  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.2",
  networks: {
    mumbai: {
      url: process.env.MUMBAI_URL,
      account: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
    }
  }
};
```

Any pointers are helpful. Thanks

Comment: can you share `hardhat.config.js`

Comment: const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require('@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades');
require("dotenv").config();
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();  
  for (const account of accounts) {
  }
});
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.2",
  networks: {
    mumbai: {
      url: process.env.MUMBAI_URL,
      account: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
    }
  }
};

Comment: maybe edit it into the question so that it is more readable

Comment: just added it to the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error states, you are importing `hardhat` module in your hardhat configuration.

```
You probably tried to import the "hardhat" module from your config or a file imported from it. This is not possible, as Hardhat can't be initialized while its config is being defined.
```

Remove the line

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

and the error should disappear

Comment: thanks, the initial error is gone. But I get a different error now ==> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTransaction' of null
    at ContractFactory.<anonymous> (C:\XYZollection\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1249:38)
    at step (C:\XYZollection\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)

Comment: I guess it is coming from your deploy script. are you sure the contract exists and under contracts directory?

Comment: yes, the contract exist correctly and I have verified the names as well. hardhat is driving me crazy with this annoying issue.

Comment: can you try to share more information about this issue and add it to your question?

Comment: let me open a new question, so that its better...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794345/error-deploying-smart-contract-using-hardhat-cannot-read-property-sendtransa

Answer (score 1):

Just remove
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

or
const { hardhatArguments } = require("hardhat");

or any other that requires hardhat