# Error deploying smart contract using hardhat -- Cannot read property 'sendTransaction' of null

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Getting the below error while trying to deploy a smart contract from hardhat. Error details

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTransaction' of null
    at ContractFactory.<anonymous> (C:\Collection\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1249:38)
    at step (C:\Collection\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Collection\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Collection\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
```

Here are the config files

1. hardhat.config.js

```
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

require("dotenv").config();
// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();  
  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.2",
  networks: {
    mumbai: {
      url: process.env.MUMBAI_URL,
      account: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
    }
  }
};
```

2. deploy.js

```
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const SuperMario = await ethers.getContractFactory("SuperMario");
  const superInstance = await SuperMario.deploy("SuperMarioCollection", "SMC");
  await superInstance.deployed();
  console.log("contract was deployed to:", superInstance.address());

  await superInstance.mint("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/XXXXXXX");
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I am trying to deploy it using the following command
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mumbai

thanks

Comment: i used exactly same config and deploy script as yours, nothing went wrong. just use`superInstance.address` instead of `superInstance.address()` but other than that all was fine

Comment: unfortunately, its the same error for me even after removing the () from address.

Answer (score 2):

Change `account` to `accounts` in the network config

Answer (score 0):

found the fix. There was an error in the hardhat.config file
instead of account:, it should have been
accounts:[process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]